# Calling then after a promise wrapped inside a function

Tags: firebase, promise

I'm wrapping a promise with firebase inside a function and I would like to call it twice, and then do something once the second call is finished. Here is my code to make it easy to understand, I'm using firebase:

```
    this.updateDB('abc');
    this.updateDB('cde');

    updateDB = (content) => {
     firebase.database().ref('something').update(content)
}
```

If I called the database update just once I could use the 'then.' and the do something, but I have to call this function twice. How can I do something once both function calls finish?

I tried to research the question got more confused.
Would appreciate any guidelines

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.update()` can return a promise, you can use `Promise.all()` with both promises to know when they are both done:

```
Promise.all(this.updateDB('abc'), this.updateDB('cde')).then(() => {
    console.log('both done here');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('an error in one or both updates occurred');
});


updateDB = (content) => {
    // return promise
    return firebase.database().ref('something').update(content);
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot jfriend00 it really solved it.
I also found that I can use Promise without '.all' for just one promise so it's really usefull
Thanks(:

Comment: For one promise, you just use `.then()` and in `this.updateDB('abc').then(result => { /* code here */})`.